# How to Nest Loop in Excel Script in order to Scan specific Range

Tags: javascript, excel, nested-loops, office-scripts

i'm converting a VBA Macro to a Excel Script in order to run a macro at Excel Web

The VBA Code:

```
//Parameters is a Sheet who has startCol/endCol Cell number and startRow/endRow numbers
// Cells 3,4 is startCol; Cells 3,5 is endCol
// Cells 3,2 is startRow; Cells 3,3 is endRow

For column = Sheets("Parameters").Cells(3,4) To Sheets("Parameters").Cells(3,5)
 For row = Sheets("Parameters").Cells(3,2) To Sheets("Parameters").Cells(3,3)
  
    //then it scan the Projects Sheet and erase the values
      Sheets("Projects").Cells(row, column) = ""
     
    Next row
Next column
```

How can I convert this to a nested loop in Javascript/Excel Script?

I've tried something like:

```
let usedRange = workbook.getWorksheet("Parameters").getRange("O5:GW40");
let rowCount = usedRange.getRowCount();
let columnCount = usedRange.getColumnCount();

for(let i = 1; i< columnCount; i++){
  for(let j = 1; j < rowCount; j++){
   if (usedRangeValues[i][j] != ""){
     usedRangeValues[i][j].setValue("");
  }
 }
}
```

But i'm not getting any step further...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your question! If you are just trying to clear values of a range, you can  use the following line of code:

```
let usedRange = workbook.getWorksheet("Parameters").getRange("O5:GW40").setValue("");
```

If you need to iterate through a range to make a check, you can use the below code. Basically, you need to first get the values of the range and iterate through those values using a nested loop. In most cases, you will start your for loops with 0 instead of 1. Also, when you set a value, you set it on a Cell or a Range, not the value array of that range.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  let usedRange = workbook.getWorksheet("Parameters").getRange("A1:C5");
  let rowCount = usedRange.getRowCount();
  let columnCount = usedRange.getColumnCount();
  let usedRangeValues = usedRange.getValues();
  for (let i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
      if (usedRangeValues[i][j] != "") {
        usedRange.getCell(i, j).setValue("");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if you need any additional help!

Answer (score 0):

To add to Petra's answer, you can also use `worksheet.getRangeByIndexes` to get the range using the values from the sheet like in your VBA code. The code would look something like this -

```js
let sheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Parameters');
      
// note the getCell is zero Indexed, so the left top corner cell is (0,0). 
// Also the return value needs to be converted to a number
let startCol = sheet.getCell(2, 3).getValue() as number;
let endCol = sheet.getCell(2, 4).getValue() as number;
let startRow = sheet.getCell(2, 1).getValue() as number;
let endRow = sheet.getCell(2, 2).getValue() as number;

let usedRange = sheet.getRangeByIndexes(startRow, startCol, endRow-startRow +1, endCol-startCol +1);
usedRange.setValue("");
```